# Visual Studio Speech Synthesis loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I know I'm trying to do something above my level for now, but I'm still trying my best, nevertheless.

Until now I was focused on `c++`->`Code::Blocks`, highschool level, but now I tried messing around in Visual Studio until I joined a project.

I have some problems with a loop (the program is based on system speech, system speech synthesis, speech recognizer and process start).

I have 2 cases :

1)Inputing the vocal command "`hi`" -> it responds back with "`hi`".
2)Inputting "`hello`" -> it responds with "opening google" & opens that speciffic webpage.

Well, if it would work as it is supposed to.
If I input "hi", it responds with "hi"->[ "opening google"+opening the page ]->in a loop

If I input "`hello`" it goes straight to the loop [ "opening google"+opening the page]
I tried some break points to see what am I doing there, but I'm hopeless.

You have the code here :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Command
{
    public partial class Speech : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        public Speech()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SpeechRecognitionEngine reco = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            Choices list = new Choices();
            list.Add(new string[] { "hi", "hello" });
            Grammar gm = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(list));

            try
            {
                reco.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                reco.LoadGrammar(gm);
                reco.SpeechRecognized += Reco_SpeechRecognized;
                reco.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                reco.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void Reco_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string a = e.Result.Text;

            switch (a)
            {
                case ("hello"):
                    {
                        s.SpeakAsync("opening google");
                        Process.Start("https://www.google.com");
                        break;
                    }
                case ("hi"):
                    {
                        s.SpeakAsync("hi");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Code]

Comment: Please share your code as text and not as image. This makes it a lot easier to copy your code to reproduce your problem. It also allows search engines to index your code.

Comment: Thanks to Trevor for taking the time to edit the code into the question, but for Andrei's benefit...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Having tested this, I got similar behaviour to you.  Upon saying either phrase, the program would sometimes repeat one or other of the responses.

Having run some tests, I believe what is happening is that the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` is not only listening to what you are saying, it's also listening to what the `SpeechSynthesizer` is playing.

To demonstrate, I changed the word list to add `cat` and `dog`, and changed the event handler as follows:

```
private void Reco_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    string a = e.Result.Text;

    switch (a)
    {
        case ("cat"):
            {
                s.SpeakAsync("dog");
                break;
            }
        case ("dog"):
            {
                s.SpeakAsync("cat");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

When I said "Cat", the system responded with "Dog".  It then heard itself saying "Dog" and responded with "Cat", to which it responded "Dog".  The end result being "Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog" for a few iterations (typically three or four time in my tests).  Conversely, when I commented out the calls to `SpeakAsync()`, I experienced no looping.  I'm not sure what causes it to stop hearing itself and therefore stop looping around, it could be some internal limitation.  Just to note I was using a headset with a microphone so it was not my microphone picking up what the speakers were playing, it was the `DefaultAudioDevice` picking up what `SpeechSynthesizer` was playing.

I would imagine it was possible to configure the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` to listen only to the Default Input Device (the microphone), or alternatively configure the `SpeechSynthesizer` to only output through the Default Output Device (the speakers) so that it does not cross the streams.  However, the documentation on how you configure the audio streams is lacking in this regard.

Quite how "hi" sounds like "hello" or how "opening google" sounds like "hello" I'm not quite certain, but with such a limited grammar it may be that the recognition engine is being quite generous on what matches.

Hope this helps